# C program Cygwin vs. Xubuntu

Tags: c, linux, network-programming, cygwin, xubuntu

I have a C program that implements a start-stop protocol and when I run this program in Xubuntu ( which is installed on the virtual machine ) I get a result/behavior different from the one I get when I run the program in Cygwin. My question is: will I get the result I get in Cygwin in other Linux distributions and my virtual machine has a problem, or similar to the one I get in Xubuntu ?

this is the code that i think it's not ok, cuz in xubuntu timestamp it's not displayed

```
void timestamp(char *timestamp) {
time_t ltime;
struct tm *timp;

ltime = time(NULL);
timp = localtime(&ltime);
sprintf(timestamp,"[%d-%d-%d %d:%d:%d]",
        timp->tm_mday, timp->tm_mon+1, timp->tm_year+1900,
        timp->tm_hour, timp->tm_min, timp->tm_sec);
}
```

and I call this function like :

```
char tim[24];
timestamp(tim);
```

Comment: The most likely conclusion is that you have one or more bugs in your code - if you fix your program then it should work correctly on all platforms.

Comment: but my code compile witout warnings or something else, and no segmentation fault

Comment: That does not mean that the program is bug free - just because it *appears* to work in some conditions is no guarantee that it is 100% correct. Many bugs are *latent*, i.e. they only show up under certain conditions, e.g. compiling and running the code on a different platform. Rule of thumb: always assume the problem is in your code - 99.9% of the time that is the correct hypothesis.

Comment: just no warnings is not enough. If your compiler would know how to code, programmers wouldn't be needed...

Comment: and how can i find this bug?

Comment: You need to learn how to use debugging tools, e.g. gdb, valgrind, etc; you also need to learn how to use unit tests, how to do stress testing, etc. These are all essential skills that any serious programmer needs to acquire.

Comment: Try building with -Wall flag set.

Comment: hints would probably be more specific if you'd describe the problem more specific.

Comment: Are you *sure* that `char tim[24]` is large enough to hold the complete time stamp ? Can you guarantee that it will never exceed 23 characters ? Ideally you should use `snprintf` rather than `sprintf` to avoid any possibility of buffer overflow.